# opening up web browser from winform

Tags: vb.net, browser

Done quite a bit of looking but not finding what i need.  From a win form i'd like to open up a web browser passing in a url.  But i need to provide authentication while doing this.  I tried just using a system.diagnostics.process.start("http://userid:pw@site") but that does not work.  Was hoping someone could lend a hand.

thanks
shannon

Using the tip.. here is what i have...

Dim m As New System.Security.SecureString
        Dim pw As String = "mypassword"

```
    For Each c As Char In pw
        m.AppendChar(c)
    Next

    Dim pis As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("http://test/pagegoingafter.aspx")
    With pis
        .UserName = "userid"
        .Password = m
        .UseShellExecute = False
    End With
    Process.Start(pis)
```

I'm getting a logon failure: unknown user name or password.
it's seems strange to me.. but if i do in firefox http://userid:mypassword@test/pagegoingafter.aspx i can get to my page.  If i do the same thing in IE 8... no joy.

so is there anything else that can be done to get IE to work.. cause i'm thinking that would allow the above code to work as well.

Comment: that the thing.  I'm trying to use Sql 2008 R2 Express advanced services reporting services.  It wants to be on a domain to allow machine other than where  it is installed at to view the reports.  The non profit i'm trying to help out does not have a domain.  So i'm trying to see if i can get the cred to be passed through an url so that they don't have to log in each time.  The login is the userid and pw at the server.  Lots of time you can get by this by creating the same accounts on all the boxes and have the same work group, but for RS, that doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

You can provide credentials to the process.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxf2saat.aspx) overload to `Process.Start` - it takes a username, password and domain.

There are other alternatives - see [this](http://astahost.com/info.php/Creating-Process-Alternate-Credentials-Createprocessasuser_t12663.html) blog post.

Comment: How does one provide credentials to a process?

Comment: @Michael Todd - by providing a username and password to it, using the right overload (or with the [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) class).